# C# Edit previous array in List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

Helly to everybody,

I want to make a simple thing:

I defined a List of the type string.
Then, I am adding some texts to the array "row".
After some time, I want to edit the previous "row" array and change e.g. row[1].

For example:

```
{ { "text1", "text2", "text3" }, 
  { "text4", "text5", "text6" }, 
  { "text7", "text8", "text9"} };
```

So I want to change "text5" in the List "rows".

My current code:

```
List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
string[] row = new string[3];
row[0] = "text1";
row[1] = "text2;
row[2] = "text3;
rows.Add(row);

row[0] = "text4";
row[1] = "text5;
row[2] = "text6;
rows.Add(row);

row[0] = "text7";
row[1] = "text8;
row[2] = "text9;
rows.Add(row);
```

So how can I edit "text5"?

Comment: `rows[1][1] = "..."`

Comment: _I defined a List of the type string_ No you didn't.

Comment: `rows` is a list of array-of-strings. You added "text5" to the 2nd array (row) in the 2nd spot. Therefore, it will be `rows[1][1]` because `rows[1]` will get you the 2nd row and then `[1]` will get you the 2nd item. I suggest you study how arrays work and fully understand them.

Comment: You are adding the same array three times, overwriting previous values

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yes, you're right. I fixed it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not work as expected, since an array is a reference type. With

```
new string[3];
```

you create an array object. With

```
rows.Add(row);
```

you add a reference pointing to this object to the list. You are not adding a copy of the array. Therefore, after calling `rows.Add(row);` three times, the 3 rows will all contain a reference to the same and unique array. Each row will contain `{ "text7", "text8", "text9" }`

You must create a new array for each row.

```
List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
string[] row = new string[3];
row[0] = "text1";
row[1] = "text2";
row[2] = "text3";
rows.Add(row);

row = new string[3];
row[0] = "text4";
row[1] = "text5";
row[2] = "text6";
rows.Add(row);

row = new string[3];
row[0] = "text7";
row[1] = "text8";
row[2] = "text9";
rows.Add(row);
```

Or, with array initializers

```
List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]>();
rows.Add(new string[] { "text1", "text2", "text3" });
rows.Add(new string[] { "text4", "text5", "text6" });
rows.Add(new string[] { "text7", "text8", "text9" });
```

Or, by combining collection and array initializers

```
List<string[]> rows = new List<string[]> {
    new string[] { "text1", "text2", "text3" },
    new string[] { "text4", "text5", "text6" },
    new string[] { "text7", "text8", "text9" }
};
```

You can then access "text5" with zero-based indexes

```
string oldValue = rows[1][1]; // 1st index selects the row, 2nd the array element.
rows[1][1] = "new text5";
```

or

```
string row = rows[1];
string oldValue = row[1];
row[1] = "new text5";
```

Since the `rows` list already contains a reference to this `row` array, now
`rows[1][1] == row[1]` and `rows[1][1] == "new text 5"`. I.e., you don't need to replace the row in the list.

Comment: Thanks for this very useful post! I could use parts of it and it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

For example based on your code:

```
// Use SetValue method
rows[1].SetValue("new value of text5", 1);

// or just by index
rows[1][1] = "new value of text5";
```